# Add timestamp label to GIF generated in EE Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, google-earth-engine-python-api, planet

I have generated a GIF using GEE Python API with Planet Labs free tropics satellite imagery from the NICFI program, and have tried to add a time stamp in my GIF animation but the GIF is not showing the timestamps

This is my code:

```
# Define a function to add date labels to images
def add_date_label(image):
  # Add a date property to the image
  date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'))
  date_string = date.format('MMM YYYY') # Format date to show only month and year
  labeled = image.set('label', date_string)
  # Return the modified image
  return labeled

# Load the image collection and add date labels to images
mina = ee.ImageCollection('projects/planet-nicfi/assets/basemaps/americas').filterDate('2016-01-01', '2020-07-01')
mina_with_labels = mina.map(add_date_label)

# Define arguments for video thumbnail
video_args = {
  'dimensions': 768,
  'region': aoi,
  'framesPerSecond': 2,
  'crs': 'EPSG:3857',
  'min': 64,
  'max': 5454,
  'gamma': 1.8,
  'bands': 'R,G,B',
}

# Get the video thumbnail URL for the image collection
gif_url = mina_with_labels.getVideoThumbURL(video_args)

# Print the URL
print(gif_url)

gif_url = mina.getVideoThumbURL(video_args)
```

Do you know whats the best method to try display timestamps into the GIF animation from the image dates?